# Multiple pages for results

Tags: php, html

On my search engine I get results via xml from blekko.com

I use: http://blekko.com/ws/?q=google/rss
And adding: `&p= *number*`

I can get different pages of results, e.g. 
`Page 1, 1 - 15 results`
`Page 2, 15 - 30 results`

Like at the bottom of google, however I also get a number of total results

With those two (total & page number) is there any way to generate the right amount of links at the bottom for a next button, page1 results, page 2 results ect...

$count is the total  and   there are 15 results per page

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want something like:

```
for($i; $i<10 && $i<$totalPages; $i++)
{
    echo '<a href="search.php?p='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what you want to do but usually to create links to different pages of results you need the total number of results and the nb of results you want to display per page. You then make a simple division to get the number of pages.